# What is this tool called for making wave surface?

Tags: power-tools, router, router-bit, tool-identification

I saw a special tool for making wave surface which looks very useful, it looks like this:
[image: Router table with bit]

It will do you a wave surface!
[image: Finished wood cut with bit]

Can someone tell me what the tool is called, that is set on the workbench?

The image is from https://youtu.be/VK_ZozyqDYQ

Comment: One other thought: it isn't clear that the toothed surfaces on that jig really add much. Yes, they create fixed parallel positions that won't slip. On the other hand, those positions may not be exactly where you would otherwise want them. It's certainly an interesting variation, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The narration of the YouTube video you linked to specifies that it's a router he's using. At 1:32 he says "then with a router bit like this one I route the zigzag shape on two faces".

The bit is called a V-joint bit. They're not all shaped exactly like the one in the video. Here's a link to [the Freud version](http://www.freudtools.com/products/product/99-038) and the [Amana Tool](http://www.amanatool.com/products/router-bits/jointing-router-bits/v-joint-router-bits/45790-carbide-tipped-v-joint-80-deg-x-1-3-8-dia-x-1-37-64-x-1-2-inch-shank.html) version.

The bit alone is likely to cost cost upwards of $60 depending on the retailer.

Comment: Many thanks!! I am new to woodworking am is interested in know every tool. And not a native English speaker:)

Answer (score 5):

The picture shows a router bit, and a router table supporting a router to drive that bit. A cheaper table can be built, but you're probably looking at several hundred dollars of tooling there.

Answer (score 5):

Keshlam and Graphus have already helpfully identified the overall setup (router table) and the exact type of bit used (V-joint), but for additional clarity, here is an annotated version of your original picture:

[image: annotated router table with bit]

Comment: Thank you, I am appreciated. I truly need to learn terminologies before I can learn woodworking in English.